# Promise.all with nested Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've nested arrays, I'm able to retrieve promises for the 2nd level array but not sure how to implement a `then` once top level finishes as well.

```
result.forEach(function(entity){ // outer list ???
    return Promise.all(entity.urls.map(function(item){
        return requestURL(item.href);
    }));
});
```

for instance if `results` has two or more items and each `item` has 10 or more urls to fetch, how would we implement `then` of `[Promise.all][1]` for all the promises. Native solution please.

Basically to handle nested arrays of promises in a right way.

**Data Structure:**

```
var result = [
    {
        urls: [
            {href: "link1"},
            {href: "link2"},
            {href: "link3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        urls: [
            {href: "link4"},
            {href: "link5"},
            {href: "link6"}
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Why don't you flaten the array of arrays to single array and then do a promise.all?

Comment: yes flattening is the solution, but how to do it in an elegant and less noisy way while using iterator patterns. I could create an array and push items to it and do a `Promise.all` at the end, but let's see if there is an elegant approach

Comment: _"I've nested arrays"_ Can you include text of array at Question?

Comment: Added data structure

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`, and wrap it inside another `Promise.all` call.

```js
var arr = [
  {subarr: [1,2,3]},
  {subarr: [4,5,6]},
  {subarr: [7,8,9]}
];
function processAsync(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(
      function() { resolve(n * n); },
      Math.random() * 1e3
    );
  });
}
Promise.all(arr.map(function(entity){
  return Promise.all(entity.subarr.map(function(item){
    return processAsync(item);
  }));
})).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can also use an immediately invoked generator. For example, to get flattened results,

```js
var arr = [
  {subarr: [1,2,3]},
  {subarr: [4,5,6]},
  {subarr: [7,8,9]}
];
function processAsync(n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(
      function() { resolve(n * n); },
      Math.random() * 1e3
    );
  });
}
Promise.all(function*() {
  for(var entity of arr)
    for(var item of entity.subarr)
      yield processAsync(item);
}()).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: the array structure is a bit like `var arr = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];` can you please update

Comment: and If I use your example with my data structure, I get an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`

Comment: please review my data structure

Comment: thanks, it's good now, question, it turns out the promise.all takes care of nested arrays too? please explain

Comment: You are probably iterating an object, which is not iterable. Try `for(var entity of result) for(var url of entity.urls) yield requestURL(url.href)`