# Uncaught (in promise) Errors when multiple Array.prototype.map() methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am trying to use async await to handle promises from buckets of requests (arrayOfArrays), however all of the requests are failing with Uncaught (in promise) 500 errors.

If I remove the bucket array (arrayOfArrays) and map directly over the original array of requests (stores) then the promises are handled correctly.

Is there a way to handle promises within multiple levels of Array.prototype.map() ?

```
    let groupSize = 20
    let arrayOfArrays = []
    let newStoreRequests
    let test
    
    for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i+=groupSize) {
      arrayOfArrays.push(stores.slice(i,i+groupSize));
    }
    
    const getNewStoreRequests = async () => {
      test = await Promise.all(
        arrayOfArrays.map(async (arr) => { 
          arr.map(async ({ id, primary }) => {
            return await axios.post(
              `${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_ENDPOINT}/dummy/encrypted_hash=${hash}&api_key=${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_API_KEY}&build=dev-dummy`,
              {
                id: id,
                store_id: storeId,
                is_primary: primary,
              }
            );
          })
        })
      )
    }

    getNewStoreRequests()

    console.log('arrayOfArrays', arrayOfArrays)
    console.log('newStoreRequests', newStoreRequests)
```

Original code that worked using the full array (The system would fail requests past the first 80~)

```
const newStoreRequests = await Promise.all(
      stores.map(async ({ id, primary }) => {
        return await axios.post(
          `${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_ENDPOINT}/dummy?encrypted_hash=${hash}&api_key=${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_API_KEY}&build=dev-dummy`,
          {
                id: id,
                store_id: storeId,
                is_primary: primary,
          }
        );
      })
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise.all with nested Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427761/promise-all-with-nested-promise-all)

Comment: A 500 error usually means an error on the server side though. Could you show us how you did it with the original array of requests?

Comment: no need to use `async/await` while mapping over `arr` - you'll get the same result without it  - an array of promises.

Comment: and `arrayOfArrays.map` returns a bunch of `undefined` wrapped in a promise.

Comment: it should be `arrayOfArrays.flatMap(arr => arr.map(({...}) => axios.post(...)))`

Comment: I have updated the post with the original code that worked

Answer (score 1):

No need to use async/await while mapping over `arr` - you'll get the same result without it - an array of promises.

Also, `arrayOfArrays.map` returns a bunch of `undefined` wrapped in a promise.

it should be `arrayOfArrays.flatMap(arr => arr.map(({...}) => axios.post(...)))`:

```js
let groupSize = 20
    let arrayOfArrays = []
    let newStoreRequests
    let test
    
    for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i+=groupSize) {
      arrayOfArrays.push(stores.slice(i,i+groupSize));
    }
    
    const getNewStoreRequests = async () => {
      test = await Promise.all(
        arrayOfArrays.flatMap((arr) =>  
          arr.map(({ id, primary }) => 
            axios.post(
              `${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_ENDPOINT}/dummy/encrypted_hash=${hash}&api_key=${REACT_APP_LAMBDA_API_KEY}&build=dev-dummy`,
              {
                id: id,
                store_id: storeId,
                is_primary: primary,
              }
            )
          )
        )
      )
    }

    getNewStoreRequests()

    console.log('arrayOfArrays', arrayOfArrays)
    console.log('newStoreRequests', newStoreRequests)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. I actually need the arrayOfArrays to be an array full of arrays with 20 objects to post to our system in order to prevent our legacy system limit failing the requests (Currently unable to up the limit). Also how would you prevent arrayOfArrays.map from returning a bunch of undefined wrapped in a promise?

Comment: @JackPainter " Also how would you prevent arrayOfArrays.map from returning a bunch of undefined wrapped in a promise?" - It was because `arrayOfArrays`' `map` callback didn't return anything. This answer fixed it by removing the braces from the arrow function, making it implicitly return.